# Java class Function doesnt work right

Tags: java, android, class

I have some very crazy Problem with my java class. The code will explan it:

This is my class:

```
public class myclass
{
    public int myint;
    public String mystring;

    public myclass()
    {
        myint = 0;
        mystring = "Test";
    }

    public void setStringInt(String s)
    {
        s = String.valueOf(myint);
    }

    public void somefunc()
    {
        setStringInt(mystring);
    }
}
```

This is a Part of the MainActivity:

```
//...
public myclass thisismyclass;
public String  mysecondstring;
//...
thisismyclass = new myclass();
thisismyclass.myint = 5;
thisismyclass.somefunc();
//...
```

The Output of thisismyclass.mystring is "Test". Why doesn't the code set it to "5"?
I tried something out. This works:

```
//...
    thisismyclass.myint = 5;
    thisismyclass.setStringInt(thisismyclass.mystring);
//...
```

But why did the other code not work?

mfg
lolxdfly

---

Edit: I am sorry.. I wrote it wrong.. I my code it was mystring!

Comment: S should be myString in the setter function

Comment: `This works:` I doubt it. `setStringInt` does virtually nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your following method

public void setStringInt(String s)
    {
        s = String.valueOf(myint);
    }

as follows

public void setStringInt(String s)
    {
        mystring  = String.valueOf(myint);
    }

Answer (score 2):

`s = String.valueOf(myint);` within `setStringInt` does **not** change the string value in the caller.

This is because the string reference is passed **by value**, as are all Java function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting `mystring` value anywhere except in the constructor. Did you mean to write this:

```
public void setStringInt(String s)
{
    mystring = String.valueOf(myint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java passes parameters by value.

When you pass that String reference into setStringInt and try to set it equal to the String value of the int state, you cannot alter the reference that's passed in.  String is immutable, so you don't get what you want.

Your logic is rather convoluted.  I can't tell what you want to do here.  But here's my best guess:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int myint;
    public String mystring;

    public MyClass()
    {
        myint = 0;
        mystring = "Test";
    }

    public void setStringInt(String s)
    {
        this.myint = Integer.valueOf(s);
        this.mystring = s;
    }

    public void setStringInt(int i) {
        this.myint = i;
        this.mystring = Integer.parseInt(i);
    }

    public void somefunc()
    {
        setStringInt(myint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should correct this to:

```
public void somefunc()
{
    setStringInt(mystring);
}
```

But as mentioned above these methods use call by value not call by references hence you won't change the callers variable.